How to handle "beginner" questions?
Specifically this is about: How do I get the location of the original audio/video file embedded on a webpage?
I know that this question isn't as deep as others. But on the other hand it is for many people a "first step" into RE. Some people have never looked at how websites work, and therefore it shouldn't be closed or downvoted - it should rather be edited to make the question more clear. 
I can imagine that in the future more questions like this are coming. What do you think?

Disallow questions that show no understanding of the system being reverse engineered.
To have a chance at reverse engineering something, knowing something about creating similar systems is basically required. The amount of possible beginner-level questions is almost limitless. Allowing them risks making this site more about teaching basics of any engineered system rather than reverse engineering.
For a Q&A site to be successful, it's important to keep a clear scope. It's also important to make the site interesting to the experts of the field. Allowing too simple questions is risky for both reasons.

Being a beginner to reverse engineering myself, my opinion on this matter is a little different.

I think questions that ask for all or a large number of steps to reverse engineer a system without showing a clear understanding of what they are doing are akin to give me the code questions on Stack Overflow and should hence be closed. We have a special close reason for that as well :




Questions that just ask for general directions to reverse engineer a non-specific/specific system should be on-topic and they should be answered with basic/general steps. In this case, we can extrapolate from the question that the OP is new to RE and is willing to work on their own (since the question is not of the previous category). Hence, helping them would make them much more likely to come back and ask more questions and over time answer, as their skill develops (Yes, I am an optimist).


